# PageMethod's onSuccess function not reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net web forms application. In the client side, I have a javascript for loop which calls a PageMethod in the code-behind. If the PageMethod executed successfully I have to execute additional javascript functionality such as updating the value of a label. The problem is when the `for` loop runs and calls the PageMethod, it never goes to the `onSuccess` method. The loop just continues and ends. I would like to know how to call the `onSuccess` method after each PageMethod call before the loop continues for the next iteration. Following is my code snippet.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var dataItem = datata[i];
    var name = dataItem.name;
    if (name !== null && name !== '') {
        PageMethods.ProcessName(name, onSuccess);
        function onSuccess(result) {
            if (result == "") {
                // code to populate a label with the value of name 
                // in each iteration
            }                       
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have to define the `onSuccess` function inside the loop? Also, what is the value of the `result` parameter when you call `onSuccess`?

Comment: If there was an error from the PageMethod, the result will have some value. If I move the onSuccess function outside the for loop, it's called however number of time the loop executed.The problem is I have to get the "name" value for each iteration. But, the onSuccess being outside the loop, I get only the "name" value of the last iteration!

Comment: This is common and well discussed problem of calling asynchronous method from a loop. Use closure `(function(n){PageMethods.ProcessName(n, onSuccess);})(name);` `onSuccess` must be defined outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can try moving the `onSuccess` function before the `ProcessName()` call. You can even move it to a local variable like this:

```
var onSuccess = function(result) {
    if (result == "") {
        //code to populate a label
    }                       
}
PageMethods.ProcessName(name, onSuccess);
```

or you can pass an anonymous function directly to the `PageMethods.ProcessName()` like this:

```
PageMethods.ProcessName(name, function(result) {
    if (result == "") {
        //code to populate a label
    }                       
});
```